# Create a calculations page that outputs user entered numbers

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've been asked to create a simple calculations page that will have simple text boxes to be filled in by the user. I want the numbers entered into the inputs to create a calculation (which I will hard code the other numbers in) that will have it's results outputted on the next page.

It would be great if someone could show me a coded example of one text box that will save the user entry, combine that with a very basic math calculation and then output the results onto another page.

e.g

(If the user has entered 1 in the text box) + 4 then output the result on a new page.

Comment: What's the actual question? Do you need help with the actual calculation, help with handing off the data between client and server, or something else? ...ah, I see Nathan got there before me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your input fields in a `form` and then use `POST` variables to do your calculations with:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

**Simple example as u asked:**

page1.php:

```
...
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
Field1: <input type="text" name="field1" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
...
```

page2.php

```
<?php
function addFour($n){  
  return $n + 4; 
}

echo addFour($_POST['field1']);
?>
```